# Get icon shortcut overlay when using IExtractIcon?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I'm working on changing some existing code that uses `IExtractIcon` to get the icon to add to an imagelist used to display files.   It looks up the location `IExtractIcon::GetIconLocation()`, checks a std::map to see if the given location/icon index hash exists, if so uses the index to the imagelist from the map, otherwise uses `IExtractIcon::Extract()` to get it add add to the imagelist and the imagelist index to the map.

That is working, but the icons for shortcuts don't have the overlay and I need to have the overlay shown.  Is there a way to use `IExtractIcon` to get the icon with the overlay?  Or way for me to add it?  Or is there a better way to do this overall and get it with the shortcut overlay (if it's a shortcut of course).

Thanks.

Comment: What about other overlays? Like tortoisesvn? Or Google drive?

Comment: they aren't important, just showing its a shortcut and not an actual file is the important thing.

Comment: @user3161924 why not simply check the file yourself to see if it is a link or not? You are not going to get that info from `IExtractIcon`.

Comment: if I look for a .lnk, how can I add the overlay to the returned icon?

Comment: In general, icon extractors will not have overlays (like shortcut ones) as they are applied later by the shell. You should use SHGetFileInfo with SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS

Comment: Please feel free to tell me if I misunderstood. Does the shortcut icon itself have an overlay?  The system automatically creates an icon for the Shell link by combining the object's icon with a small arrow (known as the system-defined link overlay icon) that appears in the lower left corner of the icon. Refer: [About Shell Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links#about-shell-links)

Comment: Also note: there can be only one overlay per icon, and there is a limit of 15 overlays per ImageList. If there are two or more overlays which apply to an item, then one will win and the others will lose,... Refer: [What are those little overlay icons: Windows 7 edition](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091209-00/?p=15723)

Comment: I ended up just using SHGetFileInfo and a hash on imagelist pointer+index+hash of type.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am not sure if the content I provided is helpful to you.